# How does Meteor’s accounts package keeps the User Login in browser?

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I need to know how does the Meteor’s Accounts Package keeps the User Login?
Is it using some cookies or sessions to keep the user login across the browser?
Is there any detailed article about the mechanism of Meteor’s Accounts Package?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know such article, but all needed information could be found in the [source code of `accounts-base` package](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/master/packages/accounts-base).

Basically, when user logs in, the [`makeClientLoggedIn()`](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/accounts-base/accounts_client.js#L405) function stores his `loginToken` and sets his `userId` to DDP connection. The latter action allows you to write something like `if (this.userId) ...` in Meteor methods on the server side — it contains `userId` of DDP connection.

`loginToken`, its expiration time and `userId` are [stored in `localStorage`](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/accounts-base/localstorage_token.js#L44). Next time you're visiting the same website (refresh your browser tab), this stored data is [loaded immediately and DDP connection is configured *before* any message are sent](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/accounts-base/localstorage_token.js#L117-L144).

Additionally, [`localStorage` is polled every 3 seconds](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/accounts-base/localstorage_token.js#L157-L184), in case another browser tab has logged user in (or logged out).